# Array Prints like List but its a single integer in variable explorer? Why?

Tags: python, arrays, integer

When ı print out the following code Q is prints like it suppose to be (3 5 7 9) sum of the numbers with the next one. but in the variable explorer its a single integer ı want to get the result Q as an array like

> Q = [3, 5, 7, 9]

```
import numpy as np
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in range(0,4):
 Q = np.array(A[i]+A[i+1])
 print(Q)

for i in range(0,4):
    Q = []
    Q.append(Q[i] + A[i]+A[i+1])
    print(Q)
```

This also doesnt work

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect `Q = np.array(1)` to do? If you wanted to create the entire resulting array, not by this algorithm but just hard-coding all the values, what would you write?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're just re-declaring `Q` each time and it's never added to some **collection** of values

Instead, start with an empty list (or perhaps a numpy array in your case) and **outside of your loop** and **append** the values to it at each loop cycle

`Q` is a numpy array, but it's not what you're expecting!

It has no dimensions and only references a single value

```py
>>> type(Q)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> print(repr(Q))
array(9)
```

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> Q = np.array([], dtype=np.uint8)
>>> for i in range(4):
...     Q = np.append(Q, A[i]+A[i+1])  # reassign each time for np
...
>>> print(Q)
[3 5 7 9]
```

Note that numpy arrays should be [reassigned via np.append](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html), while a normal python list has a [`.append()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) (which *does not* return the list, but directly appends to it)

```py
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c']  # start with a list of values
>>> l.append('d')        # use the append method
>>> l                    # display resulting list
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

If you're not forced to use a numpy array to begin with, this can be done with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

The resulting list can also be made into a numpy array afterwards

```py
>>> [(x + x + 1) for x in range(1, 5)]
[3, 5, 7, 9]
```

All together with simplified math

```py
>>> np.array([x*2+3 for x in range(4)])
array([3, 5, 7, 9])
```

Comment: "Q is a numpy array, but it only holds a single value" Not even that; the `Q` array has *zero dimensions* and remembers the value in a separate special way.

Comment: You're right! `np.array(1).shape` vs `np.array([1]).shape`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Numpy, then *use Numpy*. Start with a Numpy array (one-dimensional, containing the values), which looks like this:

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

(Yes, you initialize it *from* the list).

Or you can create that kind of patterned data using Numpy's built-in tool:

```
A = np.arange(1, 6) # it works similarly to the built-in `range` type,
# but it does create an actual array.
```

Now we can get the values to use on the left-hand and right-hand sides of the addition:

```
# You can slice one-dimensional Numpy arrays just like you would lists.
# With more dimensions, you can slice in each dimension.
X = A[:-1]
Y = A[1:]
```

And add the values together element-wise:

```
Q = X + Y # yes, really that simple!
```

And that last line is the reason you would use Numpy to solve a problem like this. Otherwise, just use a list comprehension:

```
A = list(range(1, 6)) # same as [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# Same slicing, but now we have to do more work for the addition,
# by explaining the process of pairing up the elements.
Q = [x + y for x, y in zip(A[:-1], A[1:])]
```